# ignoring the period but printing period at the end of the word

Tags: java

My code is translating regular words correctly ("nearby" to "broadside")
However, it fails by translating words with dots("nearby." to "nearby." but should be translated to "broadside.) I am not sure why the code is doing this, but as soon as it "detects" the period, it fails translating my translation table. This is my code:

```
 String token = scan.nextLine();
        String[] output = token.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
        {
            if (hashmap.containsKey(output[i]))
            {
                output[i] = hashmap.get(output[i]);
            }
            System.out.print(output[i]);
            if (i != output.length - 1)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
```

I have tried several methods (replaceAll(), split()) but without success.

Comment: I am going to assume that the hashmap contains the key "nearby". However, the regular expression will have created the output[i] of "nearby." (with the period). Thus the lookup will fail. Adjust the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to remove periods (or any other characters you wish to ignore) inside the for loop.

```
      for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            output[i] = output[i].replaceAll("\\.", ""); //Add this line (or use a new variable)
            if (hashmap.containsKey( output[i]) ) {
                output[i] = hashmap.get(output[i]);
            }
            System.out.print(output[i]);
            if (i != output.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
```

Updated solution, to retain the periods after the translation: (Use a temporary string instead of replacing the token's value)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
            String tempStr = output[i].replaceAll("\\.", "");
            if (hashmap.containsKey( tempStr ) ) {
                output[i] = hashmap.get(tempStr);
            }
            System.out.print(output[i]);
            if (i != output.length - 1) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello Bajal, I do not want to remove periods, but "separate" it from the word, so that the code translates the word correctly.

Comment: So, you want to treat either a period or a space as the delimitor on the user input?

Comment: eg. what would be expected output for "nearby. nearby something"

Comment: if  "broadside" is the translation of "nearby" then the desired output of "nearby." would be "broadside." But in this case, the code translates "nearby." to "nearby."

Comment: you were right. thank you. But the period is missing after translation. How am I going to implement it?

Comment: I edited the answer to cover that case as well. However note that even "near.by", "nearby..." etc will also be replaced with "broadside" since we are doing a replaceAll(). If you only want to translate the case with a single period at the end, use `String tempStr = output[i].substring(output[i].length() - 1))` instead.
If this sufficiently solved your problem, please "accept" this as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex instead of yours:

```
(\s+|\.+)+
```

It will not only split the token on spaces but also on periods. Like that, spaces and periods are both excluded from your output comparison.

The regex basically means: one or multiple spaces OR one or multiple dots, even if they appear multiple times in a row. This pattern will therefore also work for Strings like "wordA ...   wordB".

By the way: you can test the pattern on http://www.regexpal.com/. Just copy it to the regex field and enter some test strings in the field below. Like that you can see, where your code will split the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that your regular expression `(\\s+)` is splitting on whitespace; thus the following tokens are separate & distinct tokens

- nearby
- nearby.

and for that matter, so are these:

- nearby!
- nearby?
- nearby1234
- nearbyWithWordsSmashedTogether

When you check for that value in your replacement map, one is found and the other is not.  You'd have to modify your code to strip punctuation / numerical characters etc. before checking it in the map if you expect it to find the exact key,value pair (nearby->broadside).  (Go ahead and add something like nearby7 to your input, you should find given your current code that this is also not replaced correctly).

The key concepts to understand are:

1. What your regex is doing with respect to tokenization
2. How String keys in a map have to be exact to match

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. But I really don't know what to do. I have tried many things. None of them worked.

Comment: What if I use  substring?

Comment: You need to make sure the key you are looking up in the map is the exact same, but you don't want to modify the original token.  So you can do something like

hashmap.containsKey(output[i].replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "")

That will match the key in the map.  Then you want to pull out the replacement:
String replacement = hashmap.get(output[i].replaceAll("\\p{Punct}","");

Then you want to actually swap in the replacement in the output:
output[i] = output[i].replace(output[i], replacement)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the convenience regex methods that [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) offers. They are not capable enough. Leverage the regex API by using [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) directly, specifically [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) and [`Matcher.appendTail`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail-java.lang.StringBuffer-):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class WordReplacer {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String start = "I am nearby, very nearby.";
        Map<String, String> translation = new HashMap<>();
        translation.put("nearby", "broadside");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(start);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String group = matcher.group();
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(translation.getOrDefault(group, group)));
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

The predefined character class `\w` matches the characters `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. If this doesn't fit your needs, you can simply roll your own regex for words.

Now you don't need to care about spaces and punctuation.

Another potential problem is case sensitivity and preservation. But this seems out of scope.